# Zero Clipboard Doesn't work when it's called dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, clipboard, zeroclipboard

For coping to the clipboard I'm using [Zero Clipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/), recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript/665577#665577).

The code works perfectly fine when used in this form.

```
<div id="d_clip_button" style="background: #FFFFCC;">
    Click to copy
</div>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
                        clip.setText( '<?php echo "http://example.com/" . $var; ?>' );
                        clip.glue( 'd_clip_button' );
</script>
```

A problem occurs when this above code is called dynamically like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form action="generar.php" method="post">
Input: <input type="text" id="longUrl" name="longUrl" value="" /><br />
<input type="button" value="Acortar!" onclick="submitme()" />
<div id="resultado"></div>
</form>



<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function submitme(){
    var tosend=document.getElementById("longUrl").value;
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'generar.php',
            data: 'longUrl='+tosend,
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg){
                    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=msg;
                }
                else{
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

The "Click to copy" appears but the resource is not called correctly since it's "not flash".

Any ideas on how to make this work / what is the problem?

Thanks in advance!! Please ask for any clarification needed!

---

Could it have (don't think so) anything to do with the whole thing being nested on a `div`?

Comment: how are you going to use zeroclipboard in the second example?

Comment: @www0z0k  sorry for the delay, exactly the same way it is posted. Since the code is in generar.php but it is called and displayed by the AJAX function. See [demo](http://muycorto.com)

Comment: where should i click to copy?

Comment: @www0z0k hehe sorry! where ti says "Clic para copiar."

Comment: @www0z0k actually if you press enter (on the text box) and don't press the button it works just fine!

Comment: i clicked there and clipboard was empty. win7, firefox, debug flashplayer 10.1.85.3

Comment: @www0z0k tis is after pressing enter not the button right? in the /generar.php itself??

Comment: after pressing enter the form disappears and everything works ok. if i click the button the form remains and swf is not displayed

Comment: @www0z0k well that is exactly my problem ;) and it is strange since it should be the same content.

Comment: both versions have `<body onload='init();'>` ?

Comment: No, none of them, but is it needed in the docs (http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions#onLoad) it says >>The onLoad event is fired when the Flash movie completes loading and is ready for action. Please note that you don't need to listen for this event to set options -- those are automatically passed to the movie if you call them before it loads.

Comment: i didn't manage to make it work without it

Comment: could you provide html+js as it's returned by the server?

Comment: yes. this is the main page: http://pastie.org/1512290 this is when you press enter: http://pastie.org/1512287 (works) and this is what the DOM inspector (developer tools show) in chrome shows (since it the content is dynamically loaded ans is't not directly show in the source) http://pastie.org/1512307. Could it have something to do with the fact that it's nested inside the `<form>`??

Comment: @www0z0k I'm sorry, I answer your question but forgot to mention you. You probably did not get it.

Comment: @ Trufa - i made a demo (based on your code #2) where your button inside the form was `clip` and it worked fine

Comment: @www0z0k thanks for that! I'm really confused. I think it might be that it is not in the actual source code but I have to inspect it with the developers tools, It seems to no being able to pick up the javascript or the flash because of that (I don't know how to express this more technically)

Comment: @ Trufa - pasted http://pastie.org/pastes/1512307/text into an empty html file in the zeroclipboard folder and it worked. also there's an error on your demo page: `<div="generado">` can't be found by `getElementById` when the button is clicked. if the problem will remain after fixing the id imho `clip` should be created earlier

Comment: @www0z0k what `getElementById` do you mean? (Maybe it was just one of my tests that screwed it up)

Comment: @ Trufa - the problem is that after the button is clicked `ZeroClipboard.swf` is not loaded

Comment: @ Trufa - just used the firebug network tab)

Comment: @www0z0k that is so strange! It should be EXACTLY the same content, why would one trigger something and the other one not!

Comment: @ Trufa - let's discuss it in a more realtime mode: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/509/zero-clipboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML` doesn't execute JavaScript that gets passed through in the Ajax call.

Use jQuery's `.html()`.

```
 $("#resultado").html(msg);
```

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/17 here are some chat transcripts. Thanks @Pekka